# React internals: How does React know how to rerender an iframe correctly?

Tags: reactjs, iframe, render, virtual-dom

I was experimenting with React and rerendering iframes and I was not sure how React correctly rerenders iframes, especially ones which point to a text editor. Here is a jsFiddle showing this:

https://jsfiddle.net/augburto/fkqnm329/2/

The text editor I point to is not important but what I am doing is when you click Trigger Update, it will call a `setInterval` which will constantly set a new state and thus trigger a rerender.

What I thought might happen is that when I'm typing in the `iframe` which has a `textarea`, it will inevitably rerender and thus make me lose my text editor position but somehow I am able to type seamlessly without any issues despite seeing the rerenders come through in the `console.log`. Note I'm not suggesting it should do this -- I'm just wondering why it doesn't do that. I know [React internals do some smart things like transactions](https://gist.github.com/LeZuse/be7ee2742b8af689cfb8) but I wouldn't expect it to maintain my cursor position or what I have selected.

**So how does React handle rerendering iframes more specifically**? I have read articles (i.e. [this](https://medium.com/@ebakhtarov/handling-of-iframes-in-react-f038be46ac24#.xxfc9ff3o) and [this](https://developer.zendesk.com/blog/rendering-to-iframes-in-react) but they don't shed a lot of light on it I feel). Is it any different from regular DOM elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so after some time, I think I believe I discovered the answer. In general, because React just creates a virtual DOM and does a diff behind the scenes, it really is only looking at the iframe element and not what is generated. That is a completely separate thing where the iframe creates its own browsing context. Reading the [MDN documentation on iframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) was really informative:

> The HTML  element represents a nested browsing context, effectively embedding another HTML page into the current page. In HTML 4.01, a document may contain a head and a body or a head and a frameset, but not both a body and a frameset. However, an  can be used within a normal document body. Each browsing context has its own session history and active document. The browsing context that contains the embedded content is called the parent browsing context. The top-level browsing context (which has no parent) is typically the browser window.

I think React does do some special things when it comes to parsing an `iframe` but overall it doesn't deviate too much in general.

Also something that I think might be informative is how React handles input elements in general -- take a look at [Controlled Components](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html) in general for Forms as React has a completely separate and special way of handling those cases.